# Differentiate between a cancelled request and one that genuinely errorred using $http

Tags: angularjs

I have a refresh button on my page that when clicked calls the server for data. If clicked multiple times I want to cancel/ignore previous calls (that the client is still waiting for) and only use the most recent response data.

My service is:

```
// based on http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/24/canceling-http-requests-in-angularjs.aspx
services.factory('mySrvc', ['LoginService', '$http', '$q', function (LoginService, $http, $q) {
    var baseUrl = '...';
    return {
        GetThing: function (id) {
            var canceller = $q.defer();
            var cancel = function (reason) {
                canceller.resolve(reason);
            };
            var promise = $http({
                              method: 'GET',
                              url: baseUrl + 'things/getbyid/' + id,
                              headers: LoginService.authHeader(),
                              timeout: canceller.promise
                          }).then(function (response) {
                              return response.data;
                          });
            return {
                promise: promise,
                cancel: cancel
            };
        }
    }
});
```

And in my controller:

```
var requestInProgress = null;
var getThing = function (id) {

    if (requestInProgress !== null) {
        requestInProgress.cancel('cancel last request');
    }

    var request = mySrvc.GetThing(id);
    requestInProgress = request;
    request.promise.then(
        function (data) { // success
            // do some stuff with the data
            requestInProgress = null;
        }, function (reason) { // error
            console.log(reason);
            // need to differentiate here between a cancelled request and a genuine error...
        });
};
```

This does cancel the last request, however the 'reason' that is returned is an object, with a config, data, header, status etc. I cannot find the message 'cancel last request'. I don't care about the message itself, I just need a way to differentiate between a cancelled request and a request that has genuinely failed. How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not `ng-disabled="requestInProgress"` the button? j/c

Comment: @Asok In the scenario I gave it makes sense to disable the button, but I'm also asking it for more complex scenarios so would like to get this method working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience the cancellations usually come back with a status of 0 (rather than something like 404, 500, etc.) so I can ignore them on that basis. Perhaps someone else has a better rule than this for ignoring them, if so I'll adopt it myself.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. I will use this in the absence of a clearer answer, and I am curious to know what happened to the reason message..?

Comment: I know this is old but I found that user canceled $http requests come back with -1 status. But you cannot rely on this because blocked requests in chrome devtools now also causes status -1, so do CORs errors and possibly other situations. There is no way to discern between them I'm thinking the best way to handle this is wrap calls to $http with rxJS observable.